# Explanation of the Bitcoin-NG white paper

Tags: bitcoin

[image]
is that means only LeaderA can generate Micro Block in A epoch because those Mirco Block need the private key from A leader.
question two:
[image]

I don't understand what each item of this formula means.

Comment: This question is not about programming and therefore not on topic here. You might try bitcoin.stackexchange.com, or possibly math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.